# hide popup maker plugin link from wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I installed pop up maker and capabilities plugin in wordpress for my website. I want to create one user who is not able to see the link for pop up maker. I tried with adding user with some capability but I am not able to hide pop up maker link.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to use another capability plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`remove_menu_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) function called via the [`admin_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu) action hook. If you just want to remove the link for a single user, check the current user's ID first with [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user).

```
function remove_admin_menu_item_for_user() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    // Check to see if the current user's ID is the one we want to remove the page for
    if ( $user->ID == ??? ){
        // Use the $menu_slug for the page you want to remove
        remove_menu_page( $menu_slug );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_item_for_user' );
```

If you would prefer to use a plugin *[Admin Menu Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor)* should work as well, though you may need the Pro version.